# I can't get dictionary to work at all in Pycharm

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm

I can't get dictionary functions to work in Pycharm. I know something must be wrong with my Pycharm settings, because I can run extremely simple dictionary functions and literally nothing happens, but if I use the same code in an outside console, it works as expected.

If I code this:

```
student = {'1': 'Bill', '2': 'Ted'}

print(student)
```

I get this:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So where is my print output?

Comment: *How* are you running that in PyCharm?

Comment: Did you try simply running “python your_script.py” in your terminal?

Comment: Check what you are running. Right click on your script and select run instead of just clicking run.

Comment: The code goes well in my Pycharm 2018.2 Community Edition, right click on your python file or simply ctrl + shift + F10

Comment: Share a screenshot please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Comodo antivirus, it blocks run output in PyCharm. The solution is **Disabling all protection components**
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have no idea why my other (non-dictionary) code was working fine, but it was definitely my recently installed Comodo antivirus that caused the problem! I never would've thought of that because I wasn't getting any notification, but turning it off solved the issue.

Comment: Happy for you!! The stage is yours now.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in my Pycharm its working fine and got below result:

{'1': 'Bill', '2': 'Ted'}

Process finished with exit code 0

#

I think you are just missing 1st line of result which comes right after the path your running python file. Check again.
I used: Python 3.5 and Community version of Pycharm.